# Lodash or any import causing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, lodash, babeljs

**What I'm doing:** I'm writing a small JavaScript project using Three.JS. As I need to make some advanced operations on arrays I wanted to include lodash.

**What is wrong:** Whenever I write `import _ from 'lodash';` I reveice error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`. I'm using babel but no webpack since it's really easy JavaScript only project.

How can I fix it?
My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    <script src='../libs/three.js'></script>
    <script src='../libs/three.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../libs/PointerLockControls.js'></script>
    <script src="../libs/lodash.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='container'></div>
<div id="blocker">
    <div id="instructions">
        <strong>Click to look!</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"]
}
```

The same error is thrown if I try to import anything into `main.js` - lodash or even my own function from another file. You may notice that lodash is in package.json and in `../lib/lodash.js`. Trying to solve the issue I installed it once with yarn and downloaded the code manually the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can do `import` only in node.js scripts on your server. But on frontend you should include them like you did before (`<script src="..."></script>`) and start using it without any `import` statements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NestorYanchuk. So, when I have the <script> I should be able to start using e.g. `_.rounf()` out of the box without any additional imports or conditions?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But be sure to include it before you  include your code.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will be using packager with import: in my case this error was caused by missing:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

In my HTML file.